# Which law of logical equivalence says $P\Leftrightarrow Q ≡ (P\lor Q) \Rightarrow(P\land Q)$

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, propositional-calculus

I'm going through the exercises in the book *Discrete Mathematics with Applications*. I'm asked to show that two circuits are equivalent by converting them to boolean expressions and using the laws in this table.

$$\begin{array}{lcc}
\hphantom{1}\mathsf{1.\; Commutative\; laws:}       &  p\land q \equiv q\land p                          &  p\lor q \equiv q\lor p\\
\hphantom{1}\mathsf{2.\; Associative\; laws:}       &  (p\land q)\land r \equiv p\land (q\land r)        &  (p\lor q)\lor r \equiv p\lor (q\lor r)\\
\hphantom{1}\mathsf{3.\; Distributive\; laws:}      &  p\land (q\lor r) \equiv (p\land q)\lor (p\land r) &  p\lor (q\land r) \equiv (p\lor q)\land (p\land r)\\
\hphantom{1}\mathsf{4.\; Identity\; laws:}          &  p\land t \equiv p                                 &  p\lor c \equiv p\\
\hphantom{1}\mathsf{5.\; Negation\; laws:}          &  p\lor \lnot p \equiv t                           &  p\land \lnot p  \equiv c\\
\hphantom{1}\mathsf{6.\; Double\; negative\; law:}  &  \lnot(\lnot p) \equiv p                           &\\
\hphantom{1}\mathsf{7.\; Idempotent\; laws:}        &  p\land p \equiv p                                 &  p\lor p \equiv p\\
\hphantom{1}\mathsf{8.\; Universal\; bound\; laws:} &  p\lor t \equiv t                                  &  p\land c\equiv c\\
\hphantom{1}\mathsf{9.\; De\; Morgan}\text{'}\mathsf{s\; laws:}     &  \lnot(p\land q) \equiv \lnot p\lor \lnot q        &  \lnot(p\lor q) \equiv \lnot p\land\lnot q\\
\mathsf{10.\; Absorption\; laws:}                   &  p\lor (p\land q) \equiv p                         &  p\land (p\lor q) \equiv p\\
\mathsf{11.\; Negations\; of\; t\; and\; c:}        &  \lnot t \equiv c                                  &  \lnot c \equiv t\\
\end{array}$$

so as which law/s of logical equivalence says $P\Leftrightarrow Q ≡ (P\lor Q) \Rightarrow(P\land Q)$

I can see their equivalence clearly with a truth table. But the book is asking me to show it using the equivalence laws in the above table, and I can't see how any of them apply here. So, do any of those laws apply here in a way I'm not understanding? Or is there some other known law that does apply here?

Comment: @Zev: Wow.${}{}$

Comment: Haha thanks :) I get carried away sometimes...

Comment: @ZevChonoles teach me latex

Comment: Your second distributive law is misstated. It should be the dual of the first law, but as listed here the right side of it has only "or"s as connectives.

Comment: Note that there are no laws here which talk about $\Rightarrow$, only about $\lor$ and $\land$ and $\lnot$. You should give some definition of $\Rightarrow$ using these connectives if you want a complete answer.

Comment: @GastónBurrull: Whatever you do, don't (necessarily) follow what I do here; I do what I can given what's available in MathJax, but that often means doing something that's horribly, terribly wrong in the context of a proper LaTeX environment. Sometime when I am procrastinating (always :-/) I'll get around to making some blog posts about LaTeX. I am by no means an expert, but I guess there are a few things I've learned I could explain.

Comment: Nice long list, but obviously not enough, we need *something* that mentions $\longrightarrow$ and $\longleftrightarrow$.

Comment: @ZevChonoles I know that latex experts are quite strict (I am content if the result looks flawless)

One of those things I've learned is the difference between $f\colon A\to B$ and $f:A\to B$ (the second one is "wrong" :O)

Comment: @GastónBurrull: Other common mistakes include writing $<a,b>$ instead of $\langle a,b\rangle$ or $\{ x|\varphi(x)\}$ instead of $\{x\mid \varphi(x)\}$ or $|x|$ instead of $\lvert x\rvert$ or $||x||$ instead of $\lVert x\rVert$. On a different note, - instead of – or — (in proper LaTeX you typeset endash by two minuses -- and emdash by three ---). Also, some people write $\to$ instead of $\mapsto$, but I've seen it done on blackboard, too...

Comment: @tomasz I can't see differences (since I can't click "edit" in comments), can you put in plaintext?

Comment: @GastónBurrull: you can right-click any math formula and then choose “Show Math As -> TeX Commands”.

Comment: @tomasz sorcery!!!

Comment: @tomasz is right writing $\exists a\in\mathbb{R}\forall b\in\mathbb{R}\forall c\in\mathbb{R}\exists d\in\mathbb{R}\exists e\in\mathbb{R}$? I think that quantifiers are too tight.

Comment: @GastónBurrull: I've always had trouble with quantifiers myself. I think I'd just write the quantifiers in parentheses. Anyway, if you have any further questions, you should probably take them to tex.se, there are people there way more knowledgeable than I. :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila What's your "wow" to Zev here about?

Comment: @Doug: See the edit history to find out!

Answer (score 12):

Let's assume the following definitions:

> $\begin{array}{lc}
> \mathsf{12.\; Definition \; of \; Implication:}       &  p \Rightarrow q \equiv \neg p \lor q \\
> \mathsf{13.\; Definition \; of \; Biconditional:}     &  p \Leftrightarrow q \equiv (p \Rightarrow q) \land (q \Rightarrow p)
> \end{array}$

Then we have:
$$\begin{array}{rll}
P \Leftrightarrow Q &\equiv (P \Rightarrow Q) \land (Q \Rightarrow P) &\text{by (13)} \\
&\equiv  (\neg P \lor Q) \land (\neg Q \lor P) &\text{by (12)} \\
&\equiv  (\neg P \land (\neg Q \lor P)) \lor (Q \land (\neg Q \lor P)) &\text{by (3)} \\
&\equiv  ((\neg P \land \neg Q) \lor (\neg P \land P)) \lor ((Q \land \neg Q) \lor (Q \land P)) &\text{by (3)} \\
&\equiv  ((\neg P \land \neg Q) \lor (P \land \neg P)) \lor ((Q \land \neg Q) \lor (P \land Q)) &\text{by (1)} \\
&\equiv  ((\neg P \land \neg Q) \lor c) \lor (c \lor (P \land Q)) &\text{by (5)} \\
&\equiv  ((\neg P \land \neg Q) \lor c) \lor ((P \land Q) \lor c) &\text{by (1)} \\
&\equiv  (\neg P \land \neg Q) \lor (P \land Q) &\text{by (4)} \\
&\equiv  \neg (P \lor Q) \lor (P \land Q) &\text{by (9)} \\
&\equiv  (P \lor Q) \Rightarrow (P \land Q) &\text{by (12)} \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2):

The truth table involves "t" and "c" throughout.  So, you can rewrite the truth table using the negation laws.  That is, instead of using "t" and "c" in your truth table, use (x∨¬x), and (x $\land$ $\lnot$x) respectively.  Then, since you'll have (x∨¬x) throughout the last column of the truth table, you use the equivalence law (x∨¬x)=t in an additional column, and thus you've showed the formula true using the equivalence laws...  specifically your last two columns will look like this:

```
(x∨¬x)  t (by the equivalence law (x∨¬x)==t)   
(x∨¬x)  t (by the equivalence law (x∨¬x)==t)
(x∨¬x)  t (by the equivalence law (x∨¬x)==t)
(x∨¬x)  t (by the equivalence law (x∨¬x)==t)
```

Comment: I guess maybe I would do better to add here that since truth tables consist of no more than an exhaustive set of truth-value calculations, and since truth-value calculations can get formalized via the prtothetic of Lesniewski (p. 66-67 of Arthur Prior's Formal Logic), the above procedure should qualify as a means to write an informal proof.